# Existence of the improper integral $\int_0^\infty 1 -\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2x}\right) dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Does the integral
$$
\int_0^\infty 1 -\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2x}\right) dx
$$
exist?

I see that there is no problem for $x = 0$ as there is a continuous extension. So the question remains whether
$$
\lim_{T \to \infty} \int_T^\infty 1 - \exp\left(- \frac{1}{2x} \right) dx = 0.
$$

Comment: Hint: for large $x>0$, $1-\exp\frac{-1}{2x}\sim\frac{1}{2x}$.

Comment: By saying "exist" do you mean "converge"?